# Average Class not working

Tags: java, class

What is wrong here? It's not printing test scores in descending order, nor am I getting a value for mean. Shows up 0.0

Her are the instructions that I was given:

This class will allow a user to enter 5 scores into an array. It will then rearrange the data in descending order and calculate the mean for the data set.

Attributes:

•   data[]—the array which will contain the scores

•   mean—the arithmetic average of the scores

Methods:

•   Average—the constructor. It will allocate memory for the array. Use a for loop to repeatedly display a prompt for the user which should indicate that user should enter score number 1, score number 2, etc. Note: The computer starts counting with 0, but people start counting with 1, and your prompt should account for this. For example, when the user enters score number 1, it will be stored in indexed variable 0. The constructor will then call the selectionSort and the calculateMean methods.

•   calculateMean—this is a method that uses a for loop to access each score in the array and add it to a running total. The total divided by the number of scores (use the length of the array), and the result is stored into mean.

•   toString—returns a String containing data in descending order and the mean.

•   selectionSort—his method uses the selection sort algorithm to rearrange the data set from highest to lowest.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average
{
    private int[] data;
    private double mean;
    private int total = 0;

    public Average()
    {

        data = new int[5];
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter score number " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            data[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public void calculateMean()
    {

        int i, s = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            s = s + data[i];
        }

        mean = (double)s / (data.length);

    }

    public void selectionSort()
    {
        int maxIndex;
        int maxValue;

        for(int startScan = 0; startScan < data.length - 1; startScan++)
        {
            maxIndex = startScan;
            maxValue = data[startScan];
            for(int index = startScan + 1; index < data.length; index++)
            {
                if(data[index] > maxValue)
                {
                    maxValue = data[index];
                    maxIndex = index;
                }
            }
            data[maxIndex] = data[startScan];
            data[startScan] = maxValue;
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String output;
        output = "The test scores in descending order are \n";

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            output = output + data[i] + " ";
        }
        output = output + "\nThe average is " + mean;
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the -1 without a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need methods that *return* and *take in* values with your methods.  Here is a little mock-up of your program to show what I mean:

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
    System.out.println(calculateMean(getData()));
}

public static int[] getData()
{
    data = new int[5];
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter score number " + (i++) + ": ");
        data[i] = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    }
    s.close();
    return data;
}

public static double calculateMean(int[] data)
{

    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        s += data[i];
    }
    return mean = (double) s / (data.length);
}
```

The `getData()` method gets all the information we need from the user, and then we take that data and we pass it right along to the `calculateMean()` method.  This, in turn, spits out the average of all the scores for us.  Then all we do is print that.  I'll leave the rest up to you since this looks like homework.

---

**Trial run**:

Input: `4, 67, 3, 7, 3` (comma's indicate new line)

Output: `16.8`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My professor kinda skimmed over this section so I've been having to do it all by google searching.

Comment: You're welcome! I added some improvements upon your code in my example that you may find useful to use in your own code. Let me know if you need help with anything else.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not executing the `calculateMean()` method call first like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Average average = new Average();
    average.calculateMean();
    average.selectionSort();
    System.out.println(average.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is

```
public static void main(String[] args){
       Average avg = new Average();
       avg.selectionSort();
       avg.calculateMean();    
       System.out.println(avg);
    }
```

Everything is in place. I second @HeatfanJohn

Answer (score 1):

You never make a call to `calculateMean()`, that is why the average is zero.  In you main or where ever you create your instance of Average, you need to call `calculateMean()` before referencing `Average.toString()`.